# How to pair ICS phone with other device that has no Bluetooth PIN

Tags: bluetooth, connection-issues, bluetooth-pairing

I have a Galaxy S3 i9300 running ICS Cyanogenmod and I am trying to pair it with a Bluetooth device that has no PIN - a Wii Balance board.

The balance board does not have a PIN, however whenever I try to connect to it, my phone prompts for a password. I have tried the default 0000 and 1234 to no avail.

Is it possible to connect to a Bluetooth device without using a PIN?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll work out of the box, you'll need an app that has the required code to work around the default Bluetooth protocol of requiring a PIN for devices to be paired securely.

There is an app called [WiiScale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.broschb.wiiscale) which allows a user to link the Wii Balance Board with their Android device, provided they're rooted. The plus point of course is that it's compatible with CM which you're running. :-)

Alternate app: [FitScales](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pburton.fitscales)

Comment: WiiScale is the app that I have, but it requires your device to be paired first. I can't pair the device because my phone is asking for the bluetooth password of the wii balance board. There is no password for the wii balance board.

Comment: @jaslr Looking at the app description in the Play Store it says "Bluetooth must be synced through the application, no passcode is needed" in the first paragraph. Below that, there's a list with the instructions for pairing the scale through the app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you leave the code blank?

I can.

If not, the wii stuff controlling app can start a pairing without key from within.